# django use subquery to annotate count of distinct values of foreign key field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to annotate the quantity of distinct products but I have not been successful as of now. I get error such as:

```
ProgrammingError: subquery must return only one column
LINE 1: ..._id", "shop_selectedproduct"."create_date", COUNT((SELECT U0...
```

I have the following models:

```
class ShopItem(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    store = models.ForeignKey(to=Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class SelectedProduct(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products", null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(ShopItem, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="orders")
    status = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=OrderStatus.choices, default=OrderStatus.CART)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=True, null=True)
```

my attempt to count distinct shopitems such as `p1, p2, p3, p4 and p5` where p1 quantity should be 3 because it is selected three times, whereas others may only have a quantity of one since we only selected one of each products.

My original implementation:

```
products = order.products.all().annotate(quantity=Count("product"))
```

But this always returns 1 for all products, although they are selected multiple times.

My attempt as of now to fix this is:

```
# order = 1
SelectedProduct.objects.filter(order=order).annotate(quantity=Count(Subquery(ShopItem.objects.filter(id=OuterRef("product")))))
```

is there anyway I could count how many times a product is selected and annotate that on the selected_product such as:

```
p1.quanity
> 3
p2.quanity
> 1
p3.quanity
> 1
p4.quanity
> 1
p5.quanity
> 1
```

I'd appreciate any insights.

Edit: my further attempts:

```
subquery = Subquery(ShopItem.objects.filter(selectedproduct__order=order, selectedproduct=OuterRef('id')).order_by()
.values('selectedproduct').annotate(count=Count('pk'))
.values('count'), output_field=IntegerField())

SelectedProduct.objects.filter(order=order).annotate(child_count=Coalesce(Subquery, 0))
```

it throws `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution for this if anyone needs something similar:

```
quantity = ShopItem.objects.filter(
    id=OuterRef("product_id"),
    selectedproduct__order=order).annotate(
            quantity=Count('selectedproduct')
).values_list("quantity", flat=True)

order.products.all().select_related("product").annotate(quantity=Subquery(quantity))
```

The `quantity` subquery accepts a product id (shopitem id) with the `OuterRef` and counts how many selected products of `order`. we use `.values_list("quantity", flat=True)` to get a flat value (since the returned results are single values) of the annotated quantity. For instance, the subquery would return the value `3`, which we use directly on the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're tyring to do this on a per-order basis, you could query from the order instance itself and annotate on the related manager?

```
# Assuming the instance is self
self.products.all().annotate(
    quantity=Count(
        'product', distinct=True
    ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was my first implementation but it doesn't work as it always returns 1 for all products.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SelectedProduct.objects.filter(
   order=order
).values(
   'product'
).annotate(
   quantity=Count('product')
).order_by('product')
```

also,you can count data for all product has selected:

```
SelectedProduct.objects.values(
   'product'
).annotate(
   quantity=Count('product')
).order_by('product')
```

if you want to count all selected items for all products

```
ShopItem.objects.annotate(
   quantity=Count('selectedproduct')
)
```

## Update 1

To returns the related object fields

```
from django.db.models import F
SelectedProduct.objects.values(
   'product'
).annotate(
   quantity=Count('product'), 
   item_name = F('product__name'), 
   item_store = F('product__store'),
   # also, you can use
   #item_store_name= F('product__store__name'), 
).order_by('product')
```

Comment: Your first and second implementation is the closest to the solution! however `values('product')` only returns the product from the object. Is there any way we can return the whole object (with all the fields)?

Comment: of course,  answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Given an `order` instance if you want a collection of `ShopItem`s in that order annotated with their quantity in the order, you can query the `ShopItem` table.

```
products = (ShopItem.objects.filter(selectedproduct__order=order)
                            .annotate(quantity=Count('selectedproduct')))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This queryset though is annotating the returning and annotating shopitems instances where I am trying to annotate selected products `order.products`. There is an answer below yours that is closer, but it lacks since it is only returning a dictionary using `values` instead of the whole object. I will continue to try, thanks!